# Importing styles into a web component

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom

What is the canonical way to import styles into a web component?

The following gives me an error `HTML element <link> is ignored in shadow tree`:

```
<template>
    <link rel="style" href="foo.css" />
    <h1>foo</h1>
</template>
```

I am inserting this using shadow DOM using the following:

```
var importDoc, navBarProto;

importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

navBarProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
navBarProto.createdCallback = function() {
  var template, templateClone, shadow;

  template = importDoc.querySelector('template');
  templateClone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

  shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
  shadow.appendChild(templateClone);
};

document.registerElement('my-nav-bar', {
  prototype: navBarProto
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Now direct `<link>` tag is supported in shadow dom.

One can directly use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourcss1.css">
<link href="yourcss2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It has been approved by both **whatwg** and **W3C**.

Useful links for using css in shadow dom:

- https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#inertness-of-html-elements-in-a-shadow-tree
- https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/43c57866c2bbc20dc0deb15a721a28cbaad2140c
- https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/628

Direct css link can be used in shadow dom.

Comment: This is not working for me when I'm importing a stylesheet from an external site. Is this prohibited?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://some.site.com/style.css"/>`

Comment: What is the browser support of this? I can't find on caniuse.

Comment: Although this works, please note the browser will download your stylesheet everytime you create an instance of your custom web component, check the network tab of dev tools to confirm.

Answer (score 14):

If you need to place external styles inside the `<template>` tag you could try

```
<style> @import "../my/path/style.css"; </style>
```

however I have a feeling this will start importing *after* the element has been created.

Comment: "however I have a feeling this will start importing after the element has been created." I'm happy you bring this up -- this can be a problem when importing with `<link>` where the import will occur after web component creation, and styles will "blink" into place. Not sure if that's true for `@import` as well.

Comment: From my experience both `import` and `link` cause the stylesheet to be re-downloaded every time a component is created (check the network tab of dev tools) to confirm.

Answer (score 14):

## Answer no longer valid

The `@import` syntax was removed from `CSSStyleSheet.replace()`

- [Chrome](https://github.com/WICG/construct-stylesheets/issues/119#issuecomment-588352418)
- [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/replace#parameters)

### <s>Constructable Stylesheets</s>

This is a new feature that allows for the construction of `CSSStyleSheet` objects. These can have their contents set or imported from a css file using JavaScript and be applied to both documents and web components' shadow roots. It will be available in Chrome with version 73 and probably in the near future for Firefox.

There's a [good writeup on the Google developers site](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets) but I'll summarize it briefly below with an example at the bottom.

#### Creating a style sheet

You create a new sheet by calling the constructor:

```
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
```

#### Setting and replacing the style:

A style can be applied by calling the methods `replace` or `replaceSync`.

- `replaceSync` is synchronous, and can't use any external resources:

  ```
  sheet.replaceSync(`.redText { color: red }`);
  ```
- `replace` is [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and can accept `@import` statements referencing external resources. Note that `replace` returns a `Promise` which needs to be handled accordingly.

  ```
  sheet.replace('@import url("myStyle.css")')
    .then(sheet => {
      console.log('Styles loaded successfully');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Failed to load:', err);
    });
  ```

#### Applying the style to a document or shadow DOM

The style can be applied by setting the `adoptedStyleSheets` attribute of either the `document` or a shadow DOM.

```
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet]
```

The array in `adoptedStyleSheets` is frozen and can't be mutated with `push()`, but you can concatenate by combining with its existing value:

```
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [...document.adoptedStyleSheets, sheet];
```

#### Inheriting from the document

A shadow DOM can inherit constructed styles from the document's `adoptedStyleSheets` in the same way:

```
// in the custom element class:
this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [...document.adoptedStyleSheets, myCustomSheet];
```

Note that if this is run in the constructor, the component will only inherit the style sheets that were adopted prior to its creation. Setting `adoptedStyleSheets` in the `connectedCallback` will inherit for each instance when it is connected. Notably, this will not cause an [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

#### Example with Web Components

Let's create a component called `x-card` that wraps text in a nicely styled `div`.

```js
// Create the component inside of an IIFE
(function() {
  // template used for improved performance
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = `
    <div id='card'></div>
  `;

  // create the stylesheet
  const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
  // set its contents by referencing a file
  sheet.replace('@import url("xCardStyle.css")')
  .then(sheet => {
    console.log('Styles loaded successfully');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed to load:', err);
  });

  customElements.define('x-card', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
      });
      // apply the HTML template to the shadow DOM
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(
        template.content.cloneNode(true)
      );
      // apply the stylesheet to the shadow DOM
      this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      const card = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('card');
      card.textContent = this.textContent;
    }
  });

})();
```

```html
<x-card>Example Text</x-card>
<x-card>More Text</x-card>
```

Comment: i do not see any tracking on caniuse.com on that. What is the Firefox support for that? So far this looks like a Chrome only tech right?

Comment: @Thomas - These are now implemented by Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Comment: As usual Safari lagging behind, no `replace` or `replaceSync` support yet

Comment: `@import` support  has been deprecated for `replace` and `replaceSync`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/replace#parameters So this answer no longer works.

Comment: @run_the_race - this is correct, the answer is no longer valid as I do not see an alternative method for importing external stylesheets

Comment: It's unfortunate because it was looking like the way to do. Maybe we are supposed to perform a fetch on the CSS and put the text of the response into `replace()`, but that would not be a cached solution.

Answer (score 2):

**NB!!!**

**THIS ANSWER IS OUTDATED**

**PLEASE CHECK THE ANSWER BY *Himanshu Sharma***

Up-to-date answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202206/2035262

<del>According to [Polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#including-stylesheets-in-an-element):</del>

> <del>Polymer allows you to include stylesheets in your `<polymer-element>` definitions, a feature **not supported natively by Shadow DOM**.</del>

<del>This is a bit weird reference, but I could not google the straight one. It looks like at the moment there is no rumors about supporting links inside templates.</del>

<del>That said, whether you want to use vanilla web component, you should either inline your css with `<style>` tag, or load and apply your *css* manually in javascript.</del>

Comment: If you are using 1.0 then this is outdated: [https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html)

Comment: @7immy Yeah, this is because of serious productivity penalties.

Comment: This is older answer and outdated . See below answer .

Comment: @Himanshusharma thanks, I have updated the answer linking to your up-to-date version.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers show how to import stylesheets into a web component, but importing a single style to a shadow DOM can be done (kind-of) programmatically. This is the technique I developed recently.

*First* - make sure that you embed your component-local styles directly in a template with the HTML code. This is to make sure that the shadow DOM will have a stylesheet in your element constructor. (importing other stylesheets should be ok, but you must have one ready in the constructor)

*Second* - use a css-variable to point at a css rule to import.

```
#rule-to-import {
   background-color: #ffff00;
}

my-element {
   --my-import: #rule-to-import;
}
```

*Third* - In the component constructor, read the CSS variable and locate the pointed to style in the document stylesheets. When found, copy the string but rewrite the selector to match the internal element(s) you wish to style. I use a helper function for this.

```
importVarStyle(shadow,cssvar,target) {
    // Get the value of the specified CSS variable
    const varstyle=getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue(cssvar).trim();
    if(varstyle!="") varstyle: {
        const ownstyle=shadow.styleSheets[0];
        for(let ssheet of document.styleSheets) {   // Walk through all CSS rules looking for a matching rule
            for(let cssrule of ssheet.cssRules) {
                if(cssrule.selectorText==varstyle) {    // If a match is found, re-target and clone the rule into the component-local stylesheet
                    ownstyle.insertRule(
                        cssrule.cssText.replace(/^[^{]*/,target),
                        ownstyle.cssRules.length
                    );
                    break varstyle;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved programmatic import of all styles from the document into a web component. Using the following code I created an assignable copy of the document's CSSStyleSheetList object:

```
  function stylesSheetListCopy(from) {
  let ret = []
  for (const style_obj of from){
    let styles = ""
    for (const rule_obj of style_obj.cssRules) {
      styles += rule_obj.cssText + "\n"
    }
    let sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
    sheet.replaceSync(styles);
    ret.push(sheet)
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Then, to apply it:

```
const host = document.querySelector("#host");
const shadow = host.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
shadow.adoptedStyleSheets = [...stylesSheetListCopy(document.styleSheets),
  ...shadow.adoptedStyleSheets];
const b = document.createElement("button");
b.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4');
b.textContent = "In the shadow DOM";
shadow.appendChild(b);
```

Creating a copy was required since the following didn't work:

```
// Doesn't work:
shadow.adoptedStyleSheets = [...document.styleSheets];
// Throws exception: Can't adopt non-constructed stylesheets.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS module scripts (still not finalized, Stage 3, and currently only working in Chromium-based browsers):

```js
// import the css and directly get a constructed stylesheet from it
import css from './path/to/styles.css' assert { type: 'css' };

// ...

// then, in the constructor:
    this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets.push(css);
```

For more info: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-attributes

Answer (score -3):

Try the `<style>` element inside of `<template>`:

```
<template>
    <style>
       h1 { 
         color: red;
         font-family: sans-serif;
       }
    </style>
    <h1>foo</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: The question is about *importing* styles, not embedding.

Comment: True but I don't think you can import at all inside <template> or <style>.